# I’m having difficulty identifying this hand plane with NO identifying marks

Tags: plane, tool-identification

This is a picture of a hand plane with a hinged cover. There are no identifying marks on the metal hand plane.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I've certainly never seen any plane like it before! We could do with some further pics from different angles, + maybe one with the blade out. From the one image it's not clear if this is cast iron or folded sheet steel (which it looks like it might be). FWIW to me it looks like a handyman/utility tool, and if it does feature folded construction then it's definitely that sort of level.

Comment: It looks like the blade can be rotated, and that blade at the top has a scrub-plane profile. That makes sense, as this would not be used for finish work. That's interesting enough that we ought to see an exploded view and a few more angles. This will allow the OP and others to try a reverse image search. This is unique enough that I would expect it to be patented.

Comment: Definitely cast, weighs 753 g

Comment: Some of those joints are welds, though. Maybe just filleted for strength. The relatively high angle, and the way that edge is made does suggest a scrub plane of some sort. No idea why you need to save the shavings in a little box, though.

Comment: Thanks for the additional photos, they flesh out the picture of what shape this is and how it might have functioned a lot more (it's fairly obviously for *collecting* the shavings). Planes are used outside of a woodworking context and I even more strongly suspected that this was one of those, and as soon as I was sure that was the case here I remembered what this might be and found it online. As odd as it might seem, this is for shaving ice!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a woodworking tool.

Comment: Graphus 2 - you are correct. 
I have just also found it to be a ice shaver

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the information everyone. It is indeed a ice plane (shaver)[image]